# How do payouts for bets change as the odds change?

Tags: finance, games, odds

Say that there's a horse race between the two horses Alice and Bob. People bet on which horse will win. The "house" is taking no money off the top, so basically it's a direct transfer where everyone guesses wrong loses their money, and it all gets split between the winners (I'm pretty sure that's how it works).

My question is: how do the actual payouts work, since the odds keep changing? For example, the odds probably start out 1-to-1. Then a bunch of people bet on Alice, so now the odds are maybe 100 to 1. Then someone bets on Bob. Will their payout be ~100x if Bob wins? What about the people who bet on Alice initially? Will their payout be 2x if they win (which is to be expected by taking 1-to-1 odds)? Or ~1.01x (which are the odds that came to be much after they made their initial bet)?

Basically, I just want to know how payouts work for such gambling scenarios where the odds are theoretically ever-changing as the bets come in. Sorry if this is the wrong stackexchange for this question, but I wasn't sure where to post it @.@.